# Select options are overwritten in symfony2 . How can i avoid that

Tags: symfony, twig

```
{% for tableField in tableFieldsArr %}
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select>
        <option name="{{ tableField }}">{{ tableField }}</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

I am trying to generate a select box with its options for each `tr` row with the above code I am getting a select box with 1 item in each row. How can I fix it?

`$tablefieldsArr` comes from the controller.

Answer (score 2):

You have to move the `for` loop inside your select:

```
{% for i in 0..tableFieldsArr|length %}
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select>
      {% for tableField in tableFieldsArr %}
        <option name="{{ tableField }}">{{ tableField }}</option>
      {% endfor %}
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: if i do that Iam getting 1 select box with all options but it is restricted to 1 row,I want to repeat the select bx with all options for each row